# What is the difference between a web service and website?

Tags: web

In my app I get the form HTML of a website. That form displays customer information. Now I can parse the form and get customer information. Or I can use a web service (SOAP or whatever) and get the same information?
What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a general level, a website is displayed to a user in a browser making it consist of `GET` request through HTTP/HTTPS.  A webservice is one that responds to more than just `GET` requests (eg. `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`). This means that a user can interact with data remotely.  Like adding your post to stackoverflow.com, that meant you sent a `POST` request where stackoverflow can store the data contained in this post in some remote location, like a database.

Answer (score 1):

Web service is a solution to integrate systems and comunications between different applications. Your app is a way to interact with this Service.

Comment: thanks Rafael and bizzyb  the website can allow people to post what is the problem? the question now   is which one is more efficient